# Obtain Mail Item details from .MSG attachment

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, drag-and-drop, outlook

Is it possible to obtain Outlook Mail Item details by dragging and dropping a single attachment from a .MSG file onto a C# application? My application currently separates the contents of a .MSG when this is dropped onto my application, however I want to go a step further and obtain sender, date/time received etc from a single attachment that is part of the .msg. This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
Outlook.Application myApp = new Outlook.Application();
object selectedItem = myApp.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
Outlook.MailItem item = selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem;
string sender = item.SenderName;
```

When I try to cast selectedItem as an Outlook.Mail Item nothing happens. Any help with this would be appreciated

Thanks

Chris

Since my initial post I have been looking at other ways in which to obtain the information that Im looking for as I have not been successful with the method above..

I have looked at the following article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa219397(v=office.11).aspx and implented the code in a test project. I know initially I asked if I could obtain the msg details from the attachement, however if a user drags an attachment from the current open message then I was wondering if it were possible to obtain the message details from the ActiveExplorer method.

At the point where:

myOlSel.Item(x).SenderName & ";"

Outlook prompts me with " A program is trying to access email address..." but at this the message box hangs and I cannot select one of the options. After doing some further reading I understand why this is in place but is there anyway around it?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? If selectedItem is null then your code would cause an exception. If selectedItem is of the type Outlook.MailItem then you should be able to see the item.SenderName otherwise I think you would get an exception when trying to cast selectedItem to a different type.

If you debug you app are you then able to see what type selectedItem is?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. SelectedItem is being returned as a System._COMObject. I then added to following to obtain the type:     string type = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(selectedItem); String type is showing as MailItem but when I attempt to cast selectedItem as MailItem, item remains null.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the selectedItem is null because there actually is no selected item at index 1?

I have the follwowing at is is working (althou it's with an Appointment item)

```
Inspector activeInspector = this.OutlookApp.ActiveInspector() as Inspector;
object currentItem = activeInspector.CurrentItem;
if (currentItem != null && currentItem is AppointmentItem)
{
     AppointmentItem appItem = currentItem as AppointmentItem;
}
```

Perhaps you should use Selection[0]?

Comment: I have tried Selection[0] but I get an Array out of bounds exception(which I find odd). MSDN exmaple shows it should be selection[1]. I have attempted to cast the COM object using your code snippet but again appItem remains as null. I have also checked the type of currentItem using string itemType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(selectedItem); and itemType = MailItem so not sure what is happening here! Thanks again for your help and code snippet Nicklas.

Comment: I assume it is a VSTO plugin you're working in, right? Maybe the trouble is in the = new Outlook.Application() call. If it's VSTO i think you should use the Application instance instead of creating a new instance. See this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: No plug-in, I'm just making a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. Unless I create a new instance of Outlook.Application I cannot expose .ActiveExplorer().Selection

Comment: Okay, I'm not that familiar with direct COM/MAPI integration to Outlook. I have only looked a VSTO. 
But it seems that you would have to log in to get the Outlook reference: http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2006/05/26/79720.aspx
Anyway, I would try to be certain that the Outlook reference is 'valid' and that there actually is a selected item - perhaps by subscribing to selected item changed events somehow. I'm sorry i'm not able to be more specific.

Comment: still no luck with this! appreciate the help Nicklas